# QGIS crashing when trying to load a raster layer

Tags: qgis, raster, error, dropbox

I'm attempting to load an aerial photo for a map I'm making from a shared dropbox folder. As soon as I try to add the layer, the program freezes, and does not respond with anything besides a "program is not responding prompt". I've tried this with QGIS 3.32.1 as well as 3.28 LTR. I am able to load vector layers from the same shared folder, so I don't believe it is dropbox connection. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can download another version in qgis maybe a older version

Comment: Do you mean that you are trying to use the image from DropBox without downloading it first?

Comment: You should make a copy of the raster locally and give it a try. Also this happens to me when using QGIS on a machine with an integrated graphic card. Especially when trying to view 3D data.